# Jaxb doesn't generate Interface for element of complex type

Tags: jaxb

I have an xsd (for basecamp xml) that contains

```
<xsd:complexType name="ProjectType">
    <xsd:sequence>
        <xsd:element name="announcement"
                     type="TypedNilableStringElementType"
                     maxOccurs="1" 
                     minOccurs="1">
        </xsd:element>
        <xsd:element name="created-on"
                     type="TypedDateElementType" 
                     maxOccurs="1"
                     minOccurs="1">
        </xsd:element>
        <xsd:element name="id"
                     type="TypedIntegerElementType" 
                     maxOccurs="1"
                     minOccurs="1">
        </xsd:element>
        <xsd:element name="last-changed-on"
                     type="TypedDateTimeElementType" 
                     maxOccurs="1"
                     minOccurs="1">
        </xsd:element>
        <xsd:element name="name" 
                     type="xsd:string" 
                     maxOccurs="1"
                     minOccurs="1">
        </xsd:element>
        <xsd:element name="show-announcement"
                     type="TypedBooleanElementType" 
                     maxOccurs="1"
                     minOccurs="1">
        </xsd:element>
        <xsd:element name="show-writeboards"
                     type="TypedBooleanElementType" 
                     maxOccurs="1"
                     minOccurs="1">
        </xsd:element>
        <xsd:element name="start-page" 
                     type="xsd:string"
                     maxOccurs="1" 
                     minOccurs="1">
        </xsd:element>
        <xsd:element name="status" 
                     type="xsd:string" 
                     maxOccurs="1"
                     minOccurs="1">
        </xsd:element>
        <xsd:element name="company"
                     type="SimpleCompanyType" 
                     maxOccurs="1" 
                     minOccurs="1">
        </xsd:element>
    </xsd:sequence>
</xsd:complexType>
```

and

```
<xsd:element name="project" 
             type="ProjectType">
</xsd:element>
```

I'm looking at http://java.sun.com/javaee/5/docs/tutorial/doc/bnbah.html and can't understand what I'm doing differently from the sample schema in Table 17-13 where there is an element named purchaseOrder of type `PurchaseOrderType`. According to the tutorial, running xjc on the schema, one will get a PurchaseOrder.java interface and PurchaseOrderType.java interface.

When I run xjc on my schema I only get a ProjectType.java class, and when the xml actually consists of a single `<project ...></project>` element, this won't parse because there is no Project.java class/interface to match.

Comment: Which part of the tutorial is this described in? JAXB generally doesn't generate interfaces, just bean classes.

Comment: See the above url, table 17-13 - When I run xjc on that xsd I only get PurchaseOrderType.java and no PurchaseOrder.java. That is equivalent to my xsd, where I only get ProjectType.java and not Project.java for the <project> element. I want to the define the structure of Project as an complexType, and then both have a <project-list/> element containing a number of <project/> (that works just fine), but I also want to be able to handle just a single  <project/> where <project> is the root element, and xjc doesn't generate an element class for that.

Comment: I can add a @XmlRootElement(name = "project") to the ProjectType.java file, then I can marshall and demarshall xml with <project> as root tag. But when I already have specified an element "project" of type ProjectType in the xsd I'd suppose jaxb would do this for me automagically. I don't like having to modify the code generated by jaxb manually.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found the answer, finally (thanks google :-)

http://weblogs.java.net/blog/kohsuke/archive/2006/03/why_does_jaxb_p.html

Comment: Link is broken.