# Jaxb doesn't generate Interface for element of type

Tags: java, xml, jaxb

I am facing the same problem as specified in :
[Jaxb doesn't generate Interface for element of complex type](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2965159/jaxb-doesnt-generate-interface-for-element-of-complex-type)

As I couldn't find an answer so posting:
Basically for an element as below my application expects an interface for the element (Process). But xjc is only generating a class for type (ProcessType).

```
<xsd:element name="Process" type="xyz:ProcessType"/>
    <xsd:complexType name="ProcessType">
         <xsd:complexContent>
    </xsd:complexType>
```

Here is how I generate it :
XJB file

```
<jxb:bindings schemaLocation="root.xsd" node="/xs:schema">
    <jxb:schemaBindings>
      <jxb:package name="xyz"/>
      <jxb:nameXmlTransform>
            <jxb:elementName prefix="MyElement"/>
            <jxb:typeName prefix="MyType"/>
      </jxb:nameXmlTransform>    
    </jxb:schemaBindings>
  </jxb:bindings>
```

Is it something related to JAXB version? Or am I missing some command

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the answer after trying with multiple versions.
Basically jwsdp 1.4 generates interfaces(for element) and their implementations(complexTypes), while newer versions generate class for each complexType. As my current code is using those interfaces, I would have to stick to the old version.